# How to check if Lua table contains coordinates?

Tags: lua, path-finding, a-star, love2d

I'm trying to implement a simple pathfinding system that works with open and closed lists. I'm having trouble with the closed list. How can I check if the closed list already contains the coordinates?

```
closed[current] = true

local neighbors = getNeighbors(current[1], current[2]) -- get neighbors for the current node
for k, v in ipairs(neighbors) do -- iterate through each neighbor
  if not closed[v] then
    table.insert(open, v)
  end
end
```

getNeighbours returns every neighbour tile of a tile(x,y) in the form of coordinates(x,y). How can I check if the closed table already contains these coordinates?

Comment: If your coordinates are integers below 2^16, then use number x*65536+y as index for tile (x,y): `closed[current[1]*65536+current[2]] = true` and `if not closed[v[1]*65536+v[2]] then`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Hashing the whole table

With Lua, the key (hash) of the table can be almost everything, **EVEN** a table with 2 values.

Assuming `current[1]` and `current[2]` represents, respectively, the coordinates `x` and `y`, you can just check `closed[current]`. See the example below:

```lua
local coordinates = {
  {1.3,5},
  {2.2,3.4},
  {3,6.8}
}
local closed = {} --Empty closed list
local current = coordinates[1]  --{1.3,5}
print(closed[current]) --Not visited = nil
closed[current] = true --Marking as visited
print(closed[current]) --visited = true
print(coordinates[2]) --Not visited = nil
```

When you check `if closed[current] then ...`, the entry not existing is equivalent to `nil`, that is equivalent to `false`. If you explicitly want `false` values instead of `nil` you can do the initialisation of the closed list like this:

```
closed = {}
for i=1,#coordinates do
    closed[coordinates[i]] = false
end
```

### Hashing the coordinate values

The only problem would happen if you are somewhere in your code copying the values of the coordinates, instead of referencing the table `{x,y}`. In that case you would have different tables, so the hash will give you `false` even when the values of the 2 tables are equal.

If that is likely to happen you will need to hash with the **VALUES** instead of the table. You can do this the way Egor suggested, with a single hash, of with a double hash, like this:

```
local function listAddPoint(list,point) --Adds point (a {x,y} table) to the list
    if not list[point[1]] then
        list[point[1]] = {}
    end
    list[point[1]][point[2]] = true
end

local function listHasPoint(list,point) --Checks if the point (a {x,y} table) is on the list
    if list[point[1]] and list[point[1]][point[2]] then
        return true
    end
    return false
end

local coordinates = {
  {1.3,5},
  {2.2,3.4},
  {3,6.8}
}
local closed = {} --Empty closed list
local current = coordinates[1]  --{1.3,5}
print(listHasPoint(closed,current)) --Not visited = false
listAddPoint(closed,current)--Marking as visited
print(listHasPoint(closed,current)) --visited = true
print(listHasPoint(closed,coordinates[2])) --Not visited = false
```